# Python sort/ reverse with argparse not working

Tags: python, sorting, argparse

The mission is a simple sort/ reverse strings at the command line. A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# Sort and unsort using python
#The purpose of this program is to take strings as command line arguments and sort
#invoke by: python filename.py string string string 
# -r would should output reverse order sort

import sys  #for the command line strings to be sorted
import argparse  #this is a good getopt alternative 

#these lines are used to create the reverse switch
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r','--reverse', help='reverse flag', action='store_true')

#variables to control the switch and command line strings    
args = parser.parse_args()
strings = sys.argv

def main():  #main 

  if len(sys.argv) < 2:   # use to test in the user has inputted enough words
    print "error, you do not have enough words to sort"
    sys.exit()

  if args.reverse:  # this is the reverse sort statement
   strings.pop(0)
   strings.sort() 
   strings.reverse()
   print strings

  if not any(vars(args).values()):  # here is the normal sort statement 
   strings.pop(0)
   strings.sort()     
   print strings

if __name__== '__main__':  #if statement for the main method
   main() here
```

I keep getting unrecognized arguments errors in python 2.7

Comment: What does *"not working"* mean, exactly? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and actual outputs)?

Comment: provide your input command and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `argparse` to expect the words to sort; `sys.argv` contains the *unparsed* argument list (including the program name):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r','--reverse', help='reverse flag', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('words', nargs='+', help='words to sort')
```

The `nargs='+'` argument tells `ArgumentParser` to expect at least one argument.

After parsing, `args.words` is your list of strings.

A note on style: rather than always parse arguments, only parse command line arguments is the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard, and pass the results directly to the function rather than use globals:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r','--reverse', help='reverse flag', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('words', nargs='+', help='words to sort')

def main(strings, reverse=False):
    # do the sorting work

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args.words) < 2:
        parser.error('you do not have enough words to sort')
    main(args.words, args.reverse)
```